# createTokenWithCard completion block in swift

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I have got the number,cvc,expmonth,expyear and now I am trying to run a closure to get a token. So far I have code like this :

```
card.number = PaymentView.card.number
        card.cvc = PaymentView.card.cvc
        card.expMonth = PaymentView.card.expMonth
        card.expYear = PaymentView.card.expYear


        Stripe.createTokenWithCard(card: card, completion: {(token : STPToken, error : NSError) in


        })

    }
```

So I am then going to add an IF statement in there to check everything is cool and if so create the token. but I am getting an error at the closure saying "Missing argument for parameter 'publishableKey' in call.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance I'd say the problem is that your parameters in the closure need to be optional, since that was defined in Objective-C:

```
Stripe.createTokenWithCard(card: card, completion: {
    (token: STPToken!, error: NSError!) in
    // ...
})
```